# Measurability of integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous in the first argument, measurable in the second.

Let $m: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a finite measure.

I am wondering if the function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined as 
$$ F(x) := m\left( \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid f(x,y) \leq 0 \} \right) $$
is measurable.

What I tried to do is to claim that $F$ is upper semicontinuous. This should imply measurability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is a Caratheodory function and [must](http://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&dq=aliprantis%20border%20caratheodory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0QMzUtHUC8GJ4ATSpoC4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=aliprantis%20border%20caratheodory&f=false) therefore be jointly measurable, so $A=f^{-1}\big((-\infty,0]\big)$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\nu$ be some finite measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The Borel-$\sigma$-algebras have the property that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)$. Let $1_A$ be the indicator function of $A$. By Fubini's theorem, $$\nu\otimes m(A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} 1_A(x,y)~dm(y)~d\nu(x) $$ and the function $x\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} 1_A(x,y)~dm(y)$ is measurable. But $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} 1_A(x,y)~dm(y)=F(x)$.

Of course, a more direct argument could be made using the essential parts of the proof of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If we instead show that $F$ is upper semicontinuous, does this imply measurability? In this way we would not assume joint measurability.

Comment: @Adam, sorry if this was not clear: A function measurable in one argument and continuous in the other [is always jointly measurable](http://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&dq=aliprantis+border+caratheodory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0QMzUtHUC8GJ4ATSpoC4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=aliprantis%20border%20caratheodory&f=false). But yes, [usc functions are measurable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/show-that-every-upper-semi-continuous-real-function-is-measurable).

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, is it true that $F$ is upper semicontinuous?

Comment: I actually don't know.

Comment: A follow up. To claim joint measurability, I found that it is enough to have $f$ being a normal integrand, which is in general less strict than assuming $f$ to be Carathéodory.

Comment: Finally, where can I find a reference stating that analytic functions are measurable?

Comment: The classic reference is Dellacherie and Meyer 1978, Probability and Potential