# The measurability of $c$-transform

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, measurable-functions

In my proof of below result, I'm surprised that $f$ has no effect on the measurability of $f^c$.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Is there stronger assumption that makes $f^c$ continuous?

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $c:X \times Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$, and $f:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$. We define the $c$-transform $f^c:Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ of $f$ by
$$
f^c (y) := \inf_{x \in X} [c(x, y) - f(x)] \quad \forall y \in Y.
$$

> **Theorem:** If $c$ is upper semi-continuous (u.s.c.), then $f^c$ is u.s.c. and thus Borel measurable.

---

**My attempt:** For each $x \in X$, we define a map $g_x:Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ by
$$
g_x (y) := c(x, y) - f(x) \quad \forall y \in Y.
$$

Then $g_x$ is u.s.c. for all $x \in X$. The pointwise infimum of an arbitrary collection of u.s.c. functions [is again u.s.c.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226195/pointwise-infimum-of-an-arbitrary-collection-of-upper-semicontinuous-functions-i) Then
$$
f^c = \inf_{x \in X} g_x
$$
is u.s.c. and [thus Borel measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/show-that-every-upper-semi-continuous-real-function-is-measurable).